# Failed to read key "XXX" from store Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I've spent quite a bit of time on this and it appears that there is a setting I can't locate for the Keystore values. Problem as follows:

Im attempting to sign an APK, the project builds but errors on signing as follows:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to read key OLDKEYNAME from store "D:\Projects\Android\build-keys\_OLD\oldstorenotselectedingenerationwizard.key.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$2.invoke(BuildElements.kt:133)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$2.invoke(BuildElements.kt:110)
```

The key shown in the exception is an old key - which I don't believe I know the password for, however there is no reference I can find to the given location in the project and I have generated a new Keystore for the signing which refuses to work.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `$HOME/.android/debug.keystore` (on Windows it is `C:\Users\[your-username]\.android\debug.keystore`).

Then follow these steps to configure and generated signed apk:

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign-apk

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried that & didn't worked - so restarted the machine and its still referencing the old key+store. I attempted to reinstate the key in the old location with the details (password unsure of) but there is a file lock on the old.key.js file.  The new one generates and appears correct but is not being referenced by the build script. There is no .debug.keystore file being reinstated after the deletion of the old one - have searched elsewhere and can't see any other similar files. There is no reference to the files in the gradle build either as I've seen suggested in other posts.

Answer (score 0):

Nathan,

Overwrite the keystore location your build system is using with the new generated keystore.

Modify your app/build.gradle

```
android {

      signingConfigs {
         config {
            keyAlias 'xyz'
            keyPassword 'Abcd#033'
            storeFile file('keystore/mykey.keystore')
            storePassword 'Abcd#033'
         }

      }

 }
```

Comment: Hello, This doesn't work either its still referencing the previous key information.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm still not sure of the cause, but have updated Android to the latest version (3.4) and updated Gradle to 5.1.1. No changes to the project and is now signing properly so appears to be a bug or some configuration issue that I can't locate.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue and I goto Build > "Clean Project". Then retry again and it works.

Comment: Cleaning project can solve some build issues maybe but does nothing for a keystore error.